# Why could not be found 'IVirtualButtonEventHandle' on unity/vuforia?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, vuforia

I use vuforia SDK on Unity. When add VirtualButton, i see this problem.

`Assets/VirtualButtonEventHandle.cs(4,56): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IVirtualButtonEventHandle' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

VirtualButtonEventHandle.cs :

```
------------------
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class VirtualButtonEventHandle : MonoBehaviour **IVirtualButtonEventHandle**{
---------------
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if you've found it useful by clicking the grat tick mark. It will help others navigate to the same. Thanks.

Comment: I have resolved it. Please find my solution here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498520/ivirtualbuttoneventhandler-interface-not-implementing-in-unity/61867001#61867001 )

Comment: I have resolved this using this solution by me on another post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498520/ivirtualbuttoneventhandler-interface-not-implementing-in-unity/61867001#61867001

Answer (score 3):

using Vuforia;
solved my problem !

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing this directory:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I scratched my head for an week trying to find the same. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanx for your answer. I need not .generic directory because When I add     public class VirtualButtonEventHandle : MonoBehaviour, Vuforia.IVirtualButtonEventHandler {}    it work. –  Ercan Semerci 50 mins ago

Comment: Well, Generic usually works, so if you could mark this as the answer it may help a lot of other people.